# Flickering when drawing onto bufferedImage

Tags: java, bufferedimage, paintcomponent

I have a 3d-object composed of multiple polygons that I draw using graphics2D. When I rotate it  it, it seems as if it has not enough time to draw the entire object at every frame since at some frames, some of the polygons are simply missing(not drawn). I don't understand how that can be since I in paintComponent first draw all the polygons onto the bufferedImage myImg, and then draw the finished image onto the screen. When I remove clearRect, this issue is resolved but then of course it doesn't remove the last frame's drawing before drawing the next.

Note: I'm an amateur but I've tried really hard understanding and so this is my last resort and would be really glad to get some help. The code (with unnecessary code removed is as follows) :

```
 public class Main {

       long temp = System.currentTimeMillis() + frameRate;

       public static void main(String[] args) {
          myGUI = new GUI(width, height);       
          while(true) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= temp) {
              temp += frameRate;
              rotateObject();
              myGUI.myCanvas.myLabel.repaint();
            }
          }
       }
    }
    
    public class GUI extends JFrame {
        
        public Canvas myCanvas;
    
        public GUI(int w, int h) {
           this.setSize(w, h);
           this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    
           myCanvas = new Canvas(w, h);
           this.getContentPane().add(myCanvas);
           this.setVisible(true);
           this.pack();
        }
    }

    public class Canvas extends JPanel {
    
      public BufferedImage myImg;
      public Graphics2D g2d;
      public JLabel myLabel;
    
      public Canvas(int w, int h) {
          myImg = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
          myLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myImg));
          this.add(myLabel);
          g2d = myImg.createGraphics();
      }

      @Override
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);
          g2d.clearRect(0, 0, myImg.getWidth(), myImg.getHeight());
          g2d.setColor(Color.RED));
          g2d.fillPolygon(pointsX, pointsY, 3);
          g.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0, null);
      }
    }
```

[This is how my object is flickering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8PwO.gif)

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile so how could it flicker?   (e.g. `while("every 33 ms") {` - what do you expect that to do?).  Please post compilable code as  a [mre].

Comment: You don't need `clearRect`, it's already been done

Comment: Oh god no - `g2d = myImg.createGraphics();`, this is NOT how painting in Swing should be done, never, ever do this with a live components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really need to take the time to read through:

- [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html)
- [2D Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

These aren't "beginner" topics and a reasonable understanding of Swing in general and the language in particular would be very advantageous.

Don't, ever, use `getGraphics` on a component.  This is simply a bad idea (and I have no idea why this method is `public`).

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage myImg;
        private double rotation;

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            myImg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/happy.png"));

            Timer timer = new Timer(33, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    rotation += Math.toRadians(5);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance((getWidth() - myImg.getWidth()) / 2, (getHeight() - myImg.getHeight()) / 2);
            at.rotate(rotation, myImg.getWidth() / 2, myImg.getHeight() / 2);

            g2d.transform(at);
            g2d.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I no longer need the clearRect. I thought you needed to create a graphics context for the buffered image in order to paint on it. However theflickering is still there ( see the link at the bottom of my question). Maybe it is due to something else than the rendering process. I am aware that I should use openGL to do these kind of things, but I don't know that yet.

Comment: The flickering is caused, based on your original code, that you're trying to paint to a `JLabel` directly, but the `JLabel` is also trying to paint itself, so, as I said, don't do that, it's unnecessary, just directly to the `Graphics` context supplied to you

Comment: @SamSmith Swing is already double buffered by default, so the flickering is been caused by the paint process, it's been caused by your abuse of it